# Which settings should I use on VLC to transcode a video to play on Xbox 360?

Tags: vlc-media-player, xbox360, video-encoding, xbox-video

I tried to convert a video on VLC a few times to play on Xbox but I can't find the right settings.

I used a few formats specified [in this page](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/system/audio-video-playback) but they didn't work.

I also found [this page](https://wiki.videolan.org/Play_on_Xbox/) that basically says the same of the other, but I can't find those formats on VLC. For example, I can't see AAC as an option for audio.

Which one should I use to get the best quality?

I'm transcoding the files to play using a USB stick, not stream.

[image]

Comment: Both the links you posted say MPEG-4 is supported.

Comment: But it says MPEG-4 should use AAC, which I cannot find on VLC.